# subprocess.popen is not outputting enough meaningful error information

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, popen

What specific syntax must be changed in the Python3 function below in order to print out more useful, detailed error messages in the event that the exit code is not 0?

**BACKGROUND:**

A Python3 function successfully runs CLI commands that receive JSON responses.  But this same function fails to provide meaningful error messages when the CLI commands fail.

**CURRENT VERSION OF FUNCTION:**

Here is the function that makes the CLI call that is supposed to receive a JSON response:

```
def getShellJsonResponse(cmd):
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        cmd,
        shell=True,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    process.wait()
    data, err = process.communicate()
    print("data bytes is:", data)
    print("data string is: ", data.decode("utf-8"))
    print("err is: ", err)
    print("process.returncode is: ", process.returncode)
```

The above function works perfectly in the event that there is a successful JSON response.

**FAILURE TO PROVIDE ENOUGH DIAGNOSTIC INFORMATION ON ERROR:**

Here is what is getting printed out when an error is thrown:

```
ClientRequestError: Operation returned a 400 status code.
data bytes is: b''
data string is:
err is:  None
process.returncode is:  1
```

This returned information is useless to us because it is not detailed enough.

Comment: When you run this command in a command prompt and it fails, does it display the meaningful error message you're looking for?

Comment: @enzo No.  We get the same response in the command prompt.

Comment: To capture the stderr from your subprocess you need to set `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` as well in your Popen constructor.  That is the reason that the `ClientRequestError: Operation returned a 400 status code.` message just ended up in your terminal and not in the `err is` line.  Most web services do not provide detailed messages back to the client, but rather have that written to the server logs.  So, that is where I would look to see what is going wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: I missed that the standard error is spit out there right above your debugging messages.

```
ClientRequestError: Operation returned a 400 status code.
```

If you are unsatisfied with what your tool is printing out for error messages, I think you’ll need to take that up with the tool author.

———-

The major issue is likely that you are not capturing stderr which is where most error messages are directed.

However, the subprocess.run method is recommended over Popen nowadays.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run

So, I recommend switching to that method and using the stderr argument to capture the error output.

Comment: Thank you but the OP asks for the specific syntax so that others who read this for years to come can quickly start working with some code.

Comment: Yes, I did catch that.